# Creating list of Polygons from a text file in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have read a file of numbers and created a list of numbers from it, now I would like to create a list of Polygons based on the numbers in the list as they have a specific layout/pattern.

```
type Point = (Double, Double)

data Polygon = Polygon { v :: Int
                       , y :: Int
                       , points :: [Point]  
                       }

main = do  
    let list = []
    handle <- openFile "polycake.in" ReadMode
    contents <- hGetContents handle
    let singlewords = words contents
        list = fileToList singlewords
        n = list!!0
        list' = drop 1 list
        polygons = polyList n list'  
    hClose handle 

fileToList :: [String] -> [Int]
fileToList = map read

polyList :: Int -> [Int] -> [Polygon]
polyList n [] = return []
polyList n list = do
    let v = list!!0
        y = list!!1
        list' = drop 2 list
        pointList = take (2*v) list'
        points = getPoints pointList
        list'' = drop (2*v) list'
        poly = Polygon { v = v, y = y, points = points}
        nextPoly = polyList (n-1) list''
    return (poly:nextPoly)

getPoints :: [Int] -> [Point]
getPoints (k:v:t) = (fromIntegral k, fromIntegral v) : getPoints t
```

However I am getting the errors:

```
polycake.hs:27:17: error:
     • Couldn't match type ‘[a0]’ with ‘Polygon’
      Expected type: [Polygon]
        Actual type: [[a0]]
     • In the expression: return []
      In an equation for ‘polyList’: polyList n [] = return []
   |
27 | polyList n [] = return []
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^

polycake.hs:37:5: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Polygon]’ with ‘Polygon’
      Expected type: [Polygon]
        Actual type: [[Polygon]]
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: return (poly : nextPoly)
      In the expression:
        do let v = list !! 0
               y = list !! 1
               ....
           return (poly : nextPoly)
      In an equation for ‘polyList’:
          polyList n list
            = do let v = ...
                     ....
                 return (poly : nextPoly)
   |
37 |     return (poly:nextPoly)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am unsure why I am getting these errors.

Sample polycake.in:

```
2
4 2
0 0
4 0
4 4
0 4
6 10
3 15
10 1
12 5
11 19
9 23
6 20
```

So the first line is the # of test cases, for each test case starts with 2 numbers, the first being the number of vertices and the second being a y value that is used for a later calculation. Then the following v pairs are the vertices or Points.

Comment: Can you post a sample `polycake.in` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing `do` notation and the `return` function. `return` is not just a keyword to specify the return value of a function; it is used to "wrap" a value inside the value of a monadic type. While `[]` is a monad, you aren't using it as such in your function.

```
polyList :: Int -> [Int] -> [Polygon]
polyList n [] = []
polyList _ [x] = error "Too few points remaining"
polyList n (v:y:list') =
    let pointList = take (2*v) list' -- Note: list' may not *have* 2*v points
        points = getPoints pointList
        list'' = drop (2*v) list'
        poly = Polygon { v = v, y = y, points = points}
        nextPoly = polyList (n-1) list''
    in (poly:nextPoly)
```

Comment: Ahhh, ok that makes sense. Thanks so much!